# How to manipulate annotation text outline color in ArcEngine?

Tags: arcgis-engine, c#

I can get the color of my annotation text like this:

```
IColor TextColor = lpLabelEngine.Symbol.Color;
```

How can I get / set the outline color?

Something like this, I want a black letter with a white outline, and the white outline is 3 pixels wide.

Answer (score 1):

I started to reply with I don't think you can. except to use shadow or halo.
But did a search and walla!
Here are a couple of pages that might help...
[annotation masks](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/net/shared/geoprocessing/cartography_tools/feature_outline_masks_cartography_.htm)
[arcobjects calls](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/display/package-summary.html)